# conditional where clause SQLServer

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

I am using SQLServer 2008 and came across this problem. I have a function where a user can select multiple dates from a menu. They also have the option to tick a checkbox 'select all dates'.

If they select the checkbox my query should only return results in the given date. Thus execution a WHERE-clause.
If they did not select the checkbox but selected one or more dates; the query should be executed with a where clause.

I have 2 parameters for this.
-SelectedDates(eg. '2012-11-15','2012-11-15')
-AllDates ('X' or '')

Normally the query whould look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM x
WHERE x.date in ([Param.1])
```

So my question: how do I adapt the query in case the WHERE-clause is not needed.

FYI: the [Param.1] notation is used in the environment I am working in.

Comment: `... OR AllDates = 'X'`?

Comment: You have to use T-SQL (a stored procedure with logic i.e. you can execute one statement if a parameter value is X or another if not) see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simple, use a OR clause, if alldates is checked it will return data from all dates like this:

```
SELECT * FROM x
WHERE x.date in ([Param.1]) OR ([Param.2]) = 'X'
```

if Param.2 is checked ('X') it will ignore the result of the first condition cause you are using the OR clause.

Answer (score 1):

If all your dates are present in the control, the check all could also generate the dates so you can still use WHERE IN ('date1',....'dateN')

You also have this alternative

```
WHERE x.Date IN (.....) OR AllDates = 'X'
```

Answer (score 0):

here `AllDates` is 2nd parameter , when user check the checkbox for All dates

```
IF(AllDates is not null)
SELECT * FROM x
ELSE
SELECT * FROM x
WHERE x.date in ([Param.1])
```